# SQL Error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Tags: mysql, sql, forum

I read a few threads here about this Error-Code:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

But I can't figure it out what I am supposed to do.
I know that I have to type in this:

```
ALTER TABLE wbb1_thread ADD FULLTEXT ()
```

But I don't know what I have to insert in the brackets.

Query Error:

> Could not execute statement 'SELECT post.threadID, search_index.relevance + IF(thread.boardID=8,2,0) AS relevance FROM wbb1_post post INNER JOIN ( SELECT objectID ,MATCH (subject, message, metaData) AGAINST ('+adsad*') + (5 / (1 + POW(LN(1 + (1539014523 - time) / 2592000), 2))) AS relevance FROM wbb1_post_search_index WHERE MATCH (subject, message, metaData) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND time > ? LIMIT 2500 ) search_index ON (post.postID = search_index.objectID) LEFT JOIN wbb1_thread thread ON (thread.threadID = post.threadID) WHERE post.isDisabled = 0 AND post.isDeleted = 0 AND post.threadID <> ? AND thread.boardID IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 6'

I'll appreciate every helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how the database was designed to work... but from your query... i can see this:

The table with the Search appears to be wbb1_post_search_index, because that is the select with the "Match" statement.

So i see that you are doing a Match with 3 columns, SUBJECT, message, metaData

May you can try this command:

```
ALTER TABLE `wbb1_post_search_index` 
    ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FullText` (`SUBJECT`, `message`, `metaData`);
```

Comment: I am using a forum from Woltlab. But it is not working the error appears again and again.